# Some Css style sheet selectors ONLY taking effect on Firefox on my responsive theme

Tags: css

I have a responsive theme installed, I have used FireBug from fire fox to change the colors of certain parts of my website, and everything works perfectly on Firefox. BUT the second I look on Google chrome, Internet Explorer, and my Phone it ALL looks horribly off. Mostly it's the header widget tags as they are supposed to NOT be red.
This I think is whats not taking affect (it's the backgrounds not taking affect)? :

```
#secondary .widget_fearless_tabs .headings a {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)) repeat scroll 0 0 #333333 !important;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) !important;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    color: #CCCCCC !important;
    display: block !important;
    font-size: 1.3rem !important;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0.9em 0;
    text-align: center;
}

button:hover, .flexslider .category-label, .layout-module .widget-title > span, .pagination a:hover, .pagination .current, #primary-navigation .menu li.current-menu-item, #primary-navigation .menu li.current-menu-ancestor, #primary-navigation .menu li.current_page_item, #primary-navigation .menu > li:hover, #primary-navigation .menu > li.sfHover, #primary-navigation .menu ul a:hover, #primary-navigation .menu ul li.current-menu-item a, .review-box .heading, #searchform #searchsubmit:hover, #secondary .widget_fearless_tabs .headings a.active, section.top-reviews .review-column-1 h2, .sidebar-primary .widget-title, .wpcf7-submit:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FEFEFE, #F4F4F4) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0 !important;
    border-radius: 1px !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) inset !important;
    color: #182945 !important;
}

/* This changes colors of hover secondary widget headings like review widget */
#secondary .widget_fearless_tabs .headings a:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFFFFF, #F6F6F6) repeat scroll 0 0 padding-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0 !important;
    border-radius: 1px !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) inset !important;
    color: #40516D !important;
}
```

I don’t understand why this is not working? I have also looked at the original style sheet of my theme and can't find any thing to point me in the right direction to add to my child theme?

Comment: It's Firefox, not FireFox :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-moz surprisingly works just in mozilla. If you include the gradient for every other browser it will work in every other browser.

I always use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to create the code so I don't forget something.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your answer , My next question is in regards to the following: 1.) does this code look right like this? 2.) and if it does , does this mean that every time I add a background to a selector on my child theme I should go to colorzilla and add that nice extra chunk of css to every selector background so I can cover all browsers ? is that the proper way? The new code I am referring to , I pasted below as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Add liner gradient for all other browsers too

```
#secondary .widget_fearless_tabs .headings a:hover {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF, #F6F6F6) repeat scroll 0 0       padding-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
```

//for all other browsers

```
background: -o-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF, #F6F6F6) repeat scroll 0 0       padding-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;  
border: 1px solid #E0E0E0 !important;
border-radius: 1px !important;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) inset !important;
color: #40516D !important;
}
```